# What is the command of output superfunction in mathematica?

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, physics

I have two questions:

1. What is the command for a superfunction in Mathematica?
2. What is the difference between above superfunction and function in superspace which is odd variables times ordinary function? Are they the same thing?

In [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfunction), a superfunction S(z) of f is defined as S(z)=f(f(f(...f(t))))  (z total f's).

Answer (score 8):

At 1: The command you're probably looking for is `Nest`:

```
In[1]:= Nest[f, x, 3]

Out[1]= f[f[f[x]]]
```

At 2: This doesn't look like a question for the Mathematica tag. It seems more physics/math related. I have added tags accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

To address part 2 of your question:

Besides the prefix [super-](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/super-), there is no relation between [superfunction](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Superfunction&oldid=422143307) (meaning an iterated function) and functions in [super vector spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_vector_space).

Also, a superfunction is normally defined to be a map from a superspace to a supernumber, it does not have to be an odd element as stated in your question. See, e.g., section 1.10 of [Ideas and methods of supersymmetry and supergravity](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=jZ1Y1Z3BoicC).